# Is the output of `zfs send` deterministic?

Tags: zfs, snapshot, checksum

My goal is to generate a single checksum for the entirety of a ZFS snapshot.

If `zfs send` is deterministic (including across systems, meaning including on the system that receives the snapshot), then one way to calculate the checksum of a snapshot would be to checksum the output of `zfs send`.

So, my question is:  Is the output of `zfs send` deterministic?

Alternatively, if there is some other way to calculate the checksum of snapshot, that might suffice.

Comment: What do you mean by "checksum of a snapshot"?

Comment: I mean a checksum that will change if any bit inside the snapshot changes (due to bit-rot or disk failure).  For example, if I snapshot a ZVOL, I can calculate a checksum of the ZVOL because a ZVOL is a linear array of blocks/bytes.  I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar for a snapshot of a dataset.